# Ruby On Rails: Creating several objects of the same class in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-instances

I need to be able to create multiple objects of the same class A in one form. These objects will all have the same attributes and so therefore I do not want to create these objects separately. The only attribute that is different is an id field `b_id` which refers to instances of another class B.

My goal is to have checkboxes that correlate to all the instances of another model B and so there will be a checkbox for each instance of model B. So, when I click on the checkboxes for 3 specific instances of this other model B, I want to be able to generate 3 objects of class A that all have the same attributes except for `b_id` field.

How can I set up my form to generate multiple instances of class A?

Answer (score 0):

In your `create` action on your controller, you can get the parameter that identify the number of times the instance would be created and then do something like this:

```
number_of_instances = params[:times].to_i
number_of_instances.times do |obj|
  #=> Create instances, do whatever you want.
end
```